# Should I write a unit test for a simple interaction with RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, rxjs

Let's say we have a simple class that emits a new event to RxJS subject on window.resize event. Pay no attention that perhaps it's too complicated. The key thing is this class emits some event.

```
        export class ResizeService {
          private resizeSubject = new Subject();

          public onResize(): Observable<Window> {
            return this.resizeSubject.asObservable();
          }

          constructor(private eventManager: EventManager) {
            this.eventManager.addGlobalEventListener('window', 'resize', (e) => {
              this.resizeObject.next(<Window>event.target)   
            })
          }

          private onResize(event: UIEvent) {
            this.resizeObject.next(<Window>event.target);
          }
        }
```

The question is, speaking of unit tests for this class, should we check if new event, that we emit to RxJS subject is actually going to be received by the client, that called method `onResize`. Something like this:

```
it('should emit a value', fakeAsync(() => {
     let subscriptionWorks = false;
     fireWindowResizeEvent(new Event({width: 600; height: 400});
     resizeService.onResize().subscribe(() => subscriptionWorks = true);
     expect(subscriptionWorks).toBeTruthy();
  })
)
```

And then in case if some developer change onResizeMethod to this, the test is going to fail:

```
public onResize(): Observable<Window> {
  return this.resizeSubject.asObservable().skip(10);
}
```

Comment: No, Unit tests means you just care about checking your functionality, which is the focus should be to test the event being emitted or not. Your receiving  client can have another set of test cases to check for those events if available( may be mock in the client).

Comment: @nircraft, and how should I test this, if I can't affect my subject, as it's `private`? My suggestion is somewhere from the outside, imitating some client's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are describing is actually an integration test between your ResizeService and your client. So no you do not. No need to unit test that.

Comment: You meant "need NO unit test that", I guess. Anyway it should be tested (maybe not in terms of unit test, but in integration one) and we shouldn't just ignore this code. Is it correct?